# Splittable Bz2 input in Hadoop 1.0.0

Tags: hadoop, bzip2

I have a cluster that uses Hadoop 1.0.0 and I would like to run a MR job that processes huge bz2 files. In version 0.21.0 the Bz2 codec supported splitting of input files, however I could not find this functionality in 1.0.0. Is there any equivalent of splitting the bz2 input in 1.0.0? Or I should manually apply the patch from 0.21.0 for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.x version of Hadoop does not yet support any splittable compression codecs.
It does support Bzip2, but not splittable.
This depends on this issue
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7823
 *It currently looks like this feature wil appear in Hadoop 1.1.0*

The easiest way around this is to have a look at the cloudera packaging cdh4 which currently in beta. That has the latest Bzip2 implementation that does do splitting.

---

### *Reference:*

**Hadoop 1.0.0 API:**

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/BZip2Codec.html

```
public class BZip2Codec
extends Object
implements CompressionCodec
```

**Hadoop 0.23.1 (AFAIK will be Hadoop 2.x) API:**

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.23.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/BZip2Codec.html

```
public class BZip2Codec
extends Object
implements SplittableCompressionCodec
```

Answer (score 0):

The BZip2 Codec API can be found [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/BZip2Codec.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Pig which provides the functionality Hadoop lacks for 1.0.0. Pig will split the input file.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec` for your input split.

Comment: But it is very slow, so if you have enough space, unzip it.

Comment: You may have used bzip2. But not splittable bzip2.